# Visual Studio 2010: Why I can't change the Full Path of website?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web

I currently have a solution which recently added a new website to the TFS source control. Due to a mistake during creation, the website physical directory is like below:

> Z:\Projects\NewWebSite\NewWebSite

Instead, it should be like below:

> Z:\Projects\NewWebSite\

The problem I had was when trying to remove and add the website with the new physical path into the solution. Every time I do so, for some reason it will automatically refers to the first path. If I tried to remove the folder, it will give me an error saying it can't open the path since the folder no longer exists.

My solution is to basically unbind everything and create a new solution from scratch, then re-adding the website to the solution. My worry is that I am just working around the problem, and that it is still present somewhere in TFS, waiting to mess up someone else's solution when they check out.

So, does anyone knows what is causing this, and what is the best way to fix this sort of behavior?

Answer (score 2):

If your solution name is the same as your project name then that is the default structure. When making a new project, start by creating the solution with a unique name and then adding your project to that.

No matter what, you do actually want that structure. Its like that for the purpose of expandability. If you need to add additional projects or maybe separate your operations into different projects (like Data vs Web for instance), the Solution/Project folder setup will accommodate.

In other words, don't fight it. Just make your solution name unique from your Web application name to make it less ugly looking.

Answer (score 0):

TFS doesn't deal with physical locations at all.  This is handled by your TFS client, when you map a workspace a physical path.  This is not something that TFS deals with.

As such, i'm confused by your comments.